# Overdoing descriptive comments in class declarations

Tags: c++, coding-style

When I declare new classes I like to structure them in a specific style. Each `public`, `protected` and `private` keyword is used to either declare methods or attributes, never both. To further clarify the parts, I use short descriptive comments like in the following example:

```
class SomeRandomName 
{
  public: /* methods */
    // some public methods
  private: /* methods */
    // some private methods
  private: /* attributes */
    // some private attributes
}
```

If a class would also have protected methods and attributes, this can get pretty long and I was wondering

- Are those extra "descriptive" comments necessary, or do they make the code actually harder to read?
- and is it a good idea to separate methods and attributes in their own sections anyway?

Comment: Are these comment sections generated by an automatic-sourcecode-restructuring tool? i once worked in a project that did so. unfortunately i did not have that tool so i had to manually restructure my code changes this. way to fullfill the "definition of done" :-(.

Comment: @k3b No I also write them by hand.

Comment: I'd advise attempting to expunge "methods" and "attributes" from your thinking, at least when dealing with C++. At a guess, what you really mean are "member functions" and "data members"--but C++ doesn't have anything named a "method" or an "attribute".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objectively, these separate sections make the code harder to read, because more parts require more brainpower to process.

The comments are not really needed and just makes it less easy to read (because comments are fore important things that should not be overlooked). Instead, you should keep a small "coding style" file where you explain such conventions once for all.

I think it's a sound practice to regroup as far as possible variables on one side and functions on the other (and types in a third).

But don't try to do this by adding extra artificial barriers. These only make it harder to read, and give a false sense of security: as the compiler doesn't check, you've no insurance that there's not a mismatch somewhere.

Comment: So I should avoid using multiple `private` and `public` sections to increase the readability but still separate methods and attributes, right? But wouldn't it then be helpful to add those small comments for a somewhat stronger/more obvious separation? So that I have e.g. one `public` section which is separated by comments into an _methods_-part an _attribute_-part and a _type_-part.

Comment: @muXXmit2X a stronger separation can be obtained with an empty line. Syntactically the variables and the functions look different, so that it's quite obvious what is what.

Comment: @muXXmit2X I recommend reading about comments in https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Comments and the C++ core guidelines: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rp-direct which develop my arguments. If you have to worry about data and function separation in the public section, I'd further recommend https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-private

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the meaning of the text it is the code image that you have grown accustomed to that gives you an awareness of what you are looking at, of where you are. Anything formatted differently than what you are used to will look puzzling and be harder on your brain. If you are in a team you should eventually develop the same sense of what looks "right".

So even if you have little to say in a comment it may make sense to add it, just to give your code the consistent look you are comfortable with. Someone who does not find comfort in the way you format your code may however find it "just more noise". So, be aware of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java look the source of the Interface List, you have only empty method since it's an interface yet you have 10 lines of comments per method. Even in ArrayList you have more comments that code.

So no having comments everywhere is not necessary overdoing. However be sure that your comment is usefull, comment like "This is the price of the article" on an Attribute *price* of a class *Article* don't bring nothing.

Remember that comments are technical documentation, make short sentence, straight to the point.

See this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308581/how-should-i-order-the-members-of-a-c-class) for the ordering of declaration.

Comment: "Java does it so it's all right" is a lousy argument. Even at best, it's still an example of the appeal to authority fallacy. More realistically, it's roughly equivalent to treating a randomly chosen prison inmate as an authority on morals. Yes, it's always possible that he's completely innocent, and truly was and is a highly intelligent, educated and moral person--but you've done just about as much as you can to assure that isn't the case.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Calm down and stop extrapolating too much, I was just quoting an example that I know where I do think the comments are justified. Very long comment specifically on interface is specifically ok. Less on implementation part for me.